# Understanding jdoc:include in Joomla

Tags: php, oop, joomla, joomla2.5

I am a newbie in Joomla and want to understand one of the functionalities of the Joomla.

In joomla templates we use

```
jdoc:include type="component"
```

statement. But I am not able to understand how this functionality has been implemented in Joomla. How passing the component name in url gets rendered by the above statement of Joomla ? Please help me to understand.

Comment: what part of the manual/documentation have you read that you don't understand?

Comment: I have read jdoc statements documentation. https://docs.joomla.org/Jdoc_statements

Comment: But. I want to understand how this functionality has been implemented in joomla libraries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How passing the component name in url gets rendered by the above
>   statement of Joomla ?

To clarify the jdoc statement isn't passed in the URL. When Joomla is rendering index.php in your template and gets to `<jdoc:include type="component" />` it will replace that block of code with the actual page content.

There are a handful of different jdoc statements, the ones you'll come across most frequently are:

`<jdoc:include type="component" />`  for the page content
`<jdoc:include type="head" />` for head content of the page
`<jdoc:include type="message" />` for system messages
`<jdoc:include type="module" name="nav" title="Nav menu" />` to show a single module, in this case nav
`<jdoc:include type="modules" name="col-right" style="xhtml" />` to define position on your template where you can place output from any number of modules (with thanks to [Elin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1618513/elin) for pointing out my oversight with this one)

You will have any number of jdoc statements with different module names, the others should only appear once in your template.

More details
different jdoc statements: https://docs.joomla.org/Jdoc_statements
how the parsing works: https://api.joomla.org/cms-2.5/classes/JDocumentHTML.html

===  update ===

> how does this statement know which content page should be rendered? Is
>   this through the view="Page_name" ??

Yes that's correct. If you go

```
domain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1
```

When parsing your template's index.php file, Joomla will insert the the content for article 1 when it reaches `<jdoc:include type="component" />`

Here's a little more info about how what happens during the parsing
https://docs.joomla.org/Advanced_topics

The jdoc statements are rendered by classes in
/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks David. However, one thing I don't uderstand is "When Joomla is rendering index.php in your template and gets to <jdoc:include type="component" />  it will replace that block of code with the actual page content." how this statement knows which content page should be rendered? Is this through the view="Page_name" ??

Comment: I'd add `modules` to the list of commonly used ones.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Elin, are you thinking of something other than the 4th item in the djoc statements noted above?

Comment: Module and modules are different.

Comment: @Elin ... thank you, I was a bit slow on the uptake there. It's done :)

Answer (score 0):

**How are templates executed?**

Templates are executed in a 2-phase process that makes full use of the PHP parser to provide considerable flexibility and performance to the template designer. Templates are executed in the context of the document object so that the $this object is always the instantiation of the JDocument class.

Before template execution begins, the component will have been executed and its output buffered for later use.

Template execution then proceeds as follows:

- template parameters (if any) are loaded.
- template language (if any) is loaded.
- if legacy mode is on then the configuration variables are copied as globals.
- the template file (index.php) is loaded and executed (by PHP). The output is buffered. This is phase 1 of the 2-phase process. Everything between  tags is executed as PHP code. Everything outside of these tags is output but otherwise ignored. As the output is being buffered, nothing is sent to the client web browser at this stage.
- a favicon.ico file is looked for, first in the Joomla! root directory, then in the template root directory. The latter will override the former if found.
- the output that was buffered in phase 1 is now parsed for  elements. This is phase 2 of the process. For each jdoc element found, the appropriate renderer class is loaded and its render method is called. The output from the render method replaces the  element itself in the output buffer. In the case of module renderer classes this triggers the execution of the modules and the buffering of their output.
- Certain template-specific HTTP headers are added to the list of headers to be output.
- Control is then passed back to the JApplication object which will handle the rest of the process of getting the now rendered web page back to the client web browser.

[from Joomla Documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/How_are_templates_executed%3F)

Answer (score -2):

joomla is designed according MVC mdoel.in joomla we have these extenstions:

- component
- module
- plugin
- template
  in method jdoc:include type 
  describe usually type of extenstion.
  and jdoc:inluce also use for determine **positions of template .**